# Join query not working return null result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count of records by date and domain. php query works fine with phpmyadmin but in **php code it's return null.** I want to show by date like today, tomorrow. Join both table and count by date and domain.

**wp_domain_prefix TABLE**
[image]

**wp_projectid_1 TABLE**

[image]

PHP query

```
  <?php
 $querys = "SELECT `wp_domain_prefix.domain`, count( `wp_projectid_1.record_id` )
 FROM `wp_domain_prefix`, `wp_projectid_1` WHERE `wp_domain_prefix.domain` = `wp_projectid_1.domain` AND 
    `wp_projectid_1.datess` BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'";
    $record = mysql_query($querys);
    echo $record[count('wp_projectid_1.record_id')];
 ?>
```

Comment: not working you mean 


<?php $querys = "SELECT `wp_domain_prefix.domain`, count( `wp_projectid_1.record_id` ) FROM `wp_domain_prefix`, `wp_projectid_1` WHERE 'wp_domain_prefix.domain' = 'wp_projectid_1.domain' AND 

`wp_projectid_1.datess` BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'";
$record = mysql_query($querys);
echo $record[count('wp_projectid_1.record_id')]; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query as,

```
$querys = "SELECT wp_domain_prefix.domain, count(wp_projectid_1.record_id) FROM wp_domain_prefix, wp_projectid_1 WHERE wp_domain_prefix.domain = wp_projectid_1.domain WHERE 
wp_projectid_1.datess BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'";
$record = mysql_query($querys);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($record);
echo $row['record_id'];
```

Comment: Did you print the $row array ?

Comment: I want to today and yesterday count by domain and date join both table

Comment: got error 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in count.php on line 78  ($row = mysql_fetch_array($record);)

Comment: @user3705511 This error because of the query is failed please check again the query is work on phpmyadmin

Comment: yew working but i got output 

  Array ( [0] => designspicy.com [1] => 6 ) 

With query

<?php 
$querys = "SELECT wp_domain_prefix.domain, count(wp_projectid_1.record_id) FROM wp_domain_prefix, wp_projectid_1 Where wp_domain_prefix.domain = wp_projectid_1.domain AND 
wp_projectid_1.datess BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'";

$record = mysql_query($querys);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($record);
print_r($row);
?>

Comment: @user3705511 This is the output array. You can display by echo $row[0];

Comment: working thanx i just change your code remove 'ON' and add 'Where'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY for aggregate functions like `COUNT()`

```
$querys = 
    "SELECT wp_domain_prefix.domain, count( wp_projectid_1.record_id ) 
    FROM wp_domain_prefix, wp_projectid_1 
    WHERE wp_domain_prefix.domain = wp_projectid_1.domain
    AND wp_projectid_1.datess BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'
    GROUP BY wp_domain_prefix.domain";

$record = mysql_query($querys);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($record);
print_r($row);
```

[Read more about GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: What next code's result?

$record = mysql_query($querys);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($record);
print_r($row);

Comment: got output Array ( [0] => desigdnspicy66.com [1] => 3 )

Comment: So? desigdnspicy66.com has 3 records.
Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use mysqli instead of mysql because mysql is deprecated and support would be ended soon.

You are not fetching data from `mysql_fetch_row` after doing `mysql_query` try like this

```
$querys = "SELECT `wp_domain_prefix.domain`, count( `wp_projectid_1.record_id` ) as totalcount FROM `wp_domain_prefix`, `wp_projectid_1` WHERE `wp_domain_prefix.domain` = `wp_projectid_1.domain` AND 
`wp_projectid_1.datess` BETWEEN '2014-10-07' AND '2014-10-08'";

$record = mysql_query($querys);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($record);
print_r($row);
echo $row['totalcount'];
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in count.php on line 80

Comment: @user3705511 as per the error you have error in your query, please check query again if it's working on not

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in count.php on line 80 error in this line $row = mysql_fetch_row($record);

Comment: I mean can you run this query in mysql or phpmyadmin to check the result